# Is there an attribute "data-format" in HTML?

Tags: html

I have found this code in one video, but can't find the `data-format` attribute in HTML specification.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control bfh-phone" data-format="+7(ddd)-ddd-dd-dd" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right,  there is no `data-format` attribute in HTML5

However,  HTML5 is designed to allow some arbitrary attributes to provide some extensibility. These are the `data-*` attributes. These can be accessed by javascript to help enhance the presentation or, likely in this case, provide validation rules, or other behaviour.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Prefixing with `data-` means the arbitrary attribute can be accessed via the element's dataset list.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Answer (score 5):

All `data-*` attributes are used to interact easily with Javascript with `element.dataset.*`.

*html*

```
<div id="toto" data-test="abc"></div>
```

*javascript*

```
console.log(document.getElementById("toto").dataset.test);
// will display "abc" in console
```